# Apport-gpu-error-intel.py crash

Tags: intel-graphics, bug-reporting

Feeling disempowered by Ubuntu's new bug reporting policy/system. My Intel i5 machines have all experienced daily (if not more frequent) freezes, but it's very difficult to report bugs now and policy instead is just for ubuntu to collect counts; no way for me to see that anything is (or is not) being worked on.

I've just experienced a freeze and now on reboot I'm stuck in a cycle of "Ubuntu has an internal error" (presumably Ubuntu never experiences an *external* error...) do you want to report it? Yes. Oh another internal error...

[image: Apport crash screen]

It looks like this report could contain useful information. Is there anyway to make sure it gets provided to the people who can fix it?

Comment: Experiencing the same error! Switching between real (less frequent) and non-noticable hangs (frequently). It startet after the latest kernel update, three days ago! Any guess when this bug will be fixed. I am refusing to disable the handler because: How do I know that the bug has been fixed?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install xdiagnose version 2.5.1, which I uploaded to precise-proposed the other day.

The problem is that the Intel graphics driver has these weird "false gpu hangs". The GPU locks up but then recovers so that you don't actually notice anything, but it still is enough to trigger the error handler. Disabling apport doesn't disable this handler; 2.5.1 disables the handler directly.

Comment: I'll look into xdiagnose, thank you. Of course, the more serious issue is less the false hangs and more the *real* ones! LOL, software centre crashed while trying to enable proposed.

Comment: True, this may result in making it more difficult for people with real hangs to report them, but at least it'll stop the popups for people who aren't having hangs.

Comment: Sounds like my question is answered, albeit not in the way I'd imagined: The devs don't need the stuff because this particular problem has been identified and fixed upstream.

Comment: Wow, my computer (Dell Inspiron 14Z ultrabook) has been freezing every few days ever since I bought it ... I turned off "Enable automatic crash bug reporting" in xdiagnose last week and it hasn't crashed since. Thanks!!

Comment: is there any way around this without disabling the apport? I mean I want to report other bugs!

Comment: The crash seems to appear again in xdiagnose 3.2.3. Any idea?

Comment: I'd need to know more specifics...

Comment: Okay @Bryce, here we go :-) http://askubuntu.com/questions/277743/apport-gpu-error-intel-py-in-12-10

Answer (score 1):

You may want to disable Apport:

```
sudo gksu gedit /etc/default/apport
```

change "enabled" from "1" to "0", then save the file.

You can always re-enable it later on if you want, by changing "enabled" from "0" back to "1", or you can enable Apport temporarily, using the following command:

```
sudo service apport start force_start=1
```