# Ubuntu 12.04. Crashing

Tags: 12.04, apport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Apport-gpu-error-intel.py crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153016/apport-gpu-error-intel-py-crash)

I frequently get an error message that Ubuntu 12.04 has experienced an internal error in apport-gpu-error-intel-py.

It might be related to my screen that suspends itself after a long time of inactivity.  No keyboard or mouse movement brings it back on again, only re-boot.  Power management suspension is off.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why its crashed for you. Might be some application or H/W things didnt wakeup, when its call. Or system try to fetch data that already in very critical use.

here is some link that might be helpfull for you.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/723624
https://launchpadlibrarian.net/65090137/apport-gpu-error-intel.patch