# /usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py Error

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, apport

I was on Ubuntu 12.10 and ran the system updates and after the re-install, the system became unstable and kept prompting me with the message "System Issue" and this as the error per Ubuntu "/usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py". After I tried re-starting, the issue is still appearing and the system ultimately freezes (requiring a hard reset).

I tried a clean install of 12.10 and the system works fine until the newest updates are applied...it then returns to the same messages.

I then tried a clean install of 12.04 LTS and just like 12.10 it works until the latest updates are applied.

On 12.04, I tried to use the previous kernel - going from 3.5.0-26 to 3.5.0-23 and the issue is still there.

Currently, I'm sitting on 12.04 LTS clean install without doing the updates and the system is working.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: I hope that it isn't against the rules to post an 'answer' that isn't one - but I wanted to confirm I have the same issue, after installing updates over the weekend. I am on 12.10 with an i3 with HD2000 graphics (in case it is GPU related). When my system isn't showing the same error, it is running terribly, terribly slow.

Comment: Matt - I'm going to try this (http://askubuntu.com/questions/270658/xserver-xorg-video-intel-not-installed) and see if it works. Will post a comment later if it works or doesn't work.

Comment: Ok - the last fix did not work...my system kept freezing. I'm now going to try a 64 bit clean install.

Comment: I just tried a 64 bit clean install of 12.10 and the same problems after the updates.

Comment: Tried the fix here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1160151 - under comment #7 and the system just sat on the login screen froze.

Comment: This is apparently a weird problem with Intel driver. You can use the following temporary fix: http://askubuntu.com/questions/153016/apport-gpu-error-intel-py-crash/153480#153480