# apport-gpu-error-intel.py in 12.10

Tags: 12.10, intel-graphics, apport

The same error as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153016/apport-gpu-error-intel-py-crash/153480) appears again in Ubuntu 12.10. I get it several times a day. xdiagnose 3.2.3 is installed. Here is a screenshot of the details:

[image: apport-gpu-error-intel.py Ubuntu 12.10]

Hope you can help. If you need any more details, just comment and I will add them.